# XA error with SQL Server and Atomikos TransactionsEssentials

Tags: sql-server, atomikos

Wondering what this is about:

```
{
  "@timestamp": "2021-12-22T07:16:00.315Z",
  "log.level": "WARN",
  "message": "XA resource 'xxxxxxxxDataSource': resume for XID '3137322E31382E302E322E746D313634303135373335313132343030303032:3137322E31382E302E322E746D31' raised -3: the XA resource detected an internal error",
  "service.name": "xxxxx",
  "process.thread.name": "main",
  "log.logger": "com.atomikos.datasource.xa.XAResourceTransaction",
  "error.type": "javax.transaction.xa.XAException",
  "error.message": "The function START: failed. The status is: -3. Error: \" *** SQL_XA DTC_ERROR Context: DtcXaRM::GetTransactionCookie, StatusCode=-3 (0xFFFFFFFD), state=1, hr=0x8004D00E\"",
  "error.stack_trace": "javax.transaction.xa.XAException: The function START: failed. The status is: -3. Error: \"*** SQL_XA DTC_ERROR Context: DtcXaRM::GetTransactionCookie, StatusCode=-3 (0xFFFFFFFD), state=1, hr=0x8004D00E\"\nat com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerXAResource.DTC_XA_Interface(SQLServerXAResource.java:652)\nat com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerXAResource.start(SQLServ erXAResource.java:766)\nat com.atomikos.datasource.xa.XAResourceTransaction.resume(XAResourceTransaction.java:297)\nat com.atomikos.datasource.xa.session.BranchEnlistedStateHandler.<init>(BranchEnlistedStateHandler.java:40)\nat com.atomikos.datasour ce.xa.session.NotInBranchStateHandler.checkEnlistBeforeUse(NotInBranchStateHandler.java:46)\nat com.atomikos.datasource.xa.session.TransactionContext.checkEnlistBeforeUse(TransactionContext.java:70)\nat com.atomikos.datasource.xa.session.SessionHandle State.notifyBeforeUse(SessionHandleState.java:160)\nat com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy.enlist(AtomikosConnectionProxy.java:207)\nat com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy.invoke(AtomikosConnectionProxy.java:122)...snip"
}
```

The error snippet is from the main Spring Boot application log. SQL Server runs in a separate Docker container, and I didn't see any errors there. I've tried enabling XA support in SQL Server by running `EXEC sp_sqljdbc_xa_install`, as instructed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/understanding-xa-transactions?view=sql-server-ver15).

Can't tell if it worked, but it didn't produce any errors either.

The runtime stack contains Atomikos TransactionsEssentials 4.0.6, Mssql-jdbc 6.4.0.jre, SQL Server 2019, and Hibernate 5.3.15.Final.